# Shopping cart with multiple shipping conditions, one is free

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping, multiple

I am having a problem with free shipping conditions when my cart have more than one product and there is an other shipping condition (not free)  for at last an other product. Until there is only one product sold with free shipping conditions, everything works perfectly. Free shipping option is shown at buyer end and for all others products, the free shipping option is not shown at buyer end (free shipping is managed through attributes and cart rules).

When I have more than one product (e.g. product X has free shipping and product Y has postmail paid shipping), both products are automatically considered as paid shipping. Only paid shipping option is shown at buyer end while  the free shipping option is not shown, I suppose because cart rules are for the whole cart and not for specific items. Does anyone have advice to give me to solve this?

Another example because it's difficult to explain: I have product1 and product2 in my cart. Product1 is sold free shipping, product2 is being sold paid shipping (shipping cost=Y). My problem is that while checking out, my total shipping cost is Y+X instead being Y+zero because when in my cart there are 2 products, 1st one free shipping and 2nd one paid shipping, total shipping cost is wrongly calculated as paid for both products. When product1 is alone in the cart, shipping cost is calculated correctly as free. I do not know if I have to create a new cart rule. It's a multi vendor marketplace, so products in same cart can be from different sellers.

-- edit --
i will do an example because it's difficult to explain: i have product1 and product2 in my cart. Product1 is sold free shipping, product2 is being sold paid shipping (shipping cost=Y). my problem is that while checking out, my total shipping cost is Y+X instead being Y+zero because when in my cart there are 2 products, 1st one free shipping and 2nd one paid shipping, total shipping cost is wrongly calculated as paid for both products. when product1 is alone in the cart, shipping cost is calculated correctly as free. I do not know if i have to create a new cart rule. ( by the way, it's a multi vendor marketplace, so products in same cart can be from different sellers)

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve, it's a bit unclear from your question.

Comment: i will do an example because it's difficult to explain: